# drools time based constraints and "now"

Tags: java, date, drools

We are trying to write a drool which says something like "If the event happened in the last week, execute the consequence". We have regular java date objects representing the time the event happened, but we aren't sure how to express in the LHS of a drool that we want that date object to have taken place in the last week. Importantly, the timespan of a week is arbitrary. It could change to month or year at any time. Finally, keep in mind that our session is stateful.

I found a somewhat related question here:
[use java.util.Date in a rule's LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695466/use-java-util-date-in-a-rules-lhs) . I will quote the most relevant excerpt from the answer below:

> If you are executing within a stateless session, then your approach
> will work in combination with the Fusion operators. It is still not a
> recommended practice, however. A better approach is to define a fact,
> call it Now, which contains a single Date field. Initialize and insert
> it along with your other facts then reason against it instead of a
> global.
>
> If you have a stateful session, it gets more tricky because
> real time is passing even while the session is idle, meaning your Now
> fact is getting more and more out of date. The way we have solved this
> is via the use of a WorkingMemoryEventListener. We use the
> objectInserted, objectRetracted, and objectUpdated methods of this
> listener to keep our Now fact current (we do not care about precision
> less than one minute so we check whether a minute has passed from the
> last update to avoid unnecessary overhead). Rules won't evaluate if
> working memory isn't changing, so using this listener is sufficient to
> ensure that Now is updated when it needs to be (unless you have
> queries that depend on the current value of Now, but that's another
> topic).

In the answer, the author describes problems with the representation of "now". His solution seems hacky and the answer was posted in a much earlier version of drools. I'm making a new question here to give better attention to this question specifically rather than the passing treatment it gets in the one I linked.

**UPDATE:**

Timestamps are the simple java.util.Date object.

Events are added to the session via api call. The stateful session is an object held by a java based api. The api adds events to the knowledge session when they are submitted. FireAllRules occurs about once per second.

Comment: Reacted to your update. - RBS are hardly real-time, so you have to make allowances.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean "BRS"? If not, what do you mean by "RBS"?

Comment: RBS = Rule Based System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental question (as so often) is what the requirement *really* means. An event "happening in the last week" could be anything happening 7*24*60*60 seconds ago; it could be something that has happened from Monday 20151228 up to now, or from Sunday 20151227 until now, or maybe something similar where just the date matters and not the time of the day.

Ask what it really means, and rephrase your question accordingly.

If you do need a sliding window, going back from "now", i.e., verily this moment, for a certain time interval (of *w* seconds), you still need to define the speed and accuracy with which this check has to be performed. **Drools does not have a continually updated notion of "now" in its absolute sense.** It is possible to create and maintain a fact representing an *approximation* of "now", using a timer (which is preferable to using a listener). The Now-fact has to be updated periodically, every *d* seconds. If you insert a new event with a time stamp *after* the last update of Now, it will not be recognized for up to *d* seconds. (And if you insert a new event with a time stamp between *w* and *w* + *d* seconds in the past, it is possible that it triggers the rule.)

Since you haven't indicated how you insert events and how their time stamps are implemented I cannot provide rules illustrating what I have outlined. See the Drools documentation about "Timers and Calendars".

**Edit**

What has not been said in the question is the relation of an event's *time* (i.e., when it really happened in the real world) and its *timestamp* (i.e., when it was entered into Working Memory). Rules checking for an events *timestamp* being in the last week or month or second are futile: this will be invariably true.

If you call fireAllRules repeatedly, updating the time horizon with a timestamp 1 week (month,...) back before the call is one simple way. Or update Now before each call. Both is far from "hacky".

Comment: The timestamp on the event bean can be considered to be "when it really happened". There are only a matter of seconds(at most) between the real time event and when the object is created. For our purposes, the disconnect is not a problem. We're going try inserting a NowFact which receives updates either from a timer or just prior to the re-firing of fireAllRules.

Comment: So if all events are so close to "now", they'll all fire a rule that checks whether they have happened during the last week. You might as well write a simple rule checking for a new fact and forget about "now" and "now - one week" etc.

Comment: Let's say we are trying to figure out if the temperature is going down quickly. Specifically, we want to know if the temperature has dropped more than 7 degrees in the last week. This is the sort of constraint we are trying to express. It isn't as simple as "did this one thing happen recently". It is did these two things happen recently (in the last week, or month) and is the difference in their values over a certain absolute value.

Comment: So if the temperature goes down by 7°, it does so right at the moment when it reaches x - 7. However, in this case the issue is: when do you modify the starting temperature x, or how do you keep track of past temperature readings.  - You have asked the wrong question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but would appreciate you expounding. Our events are stored as facts. So, a fact is inserted when a temperature reading happens. This means of course that all past readings are available for evaluation by the engine. We were attempting to write a constraint which matched on two Fact() objects whose Fact.getTimeStamp() objects were less than one week apart.

Comment: We are getting there... You can relate the time stamps of events using temporal operators. Assuming that events older that the "event horizon" are removed from WM, you just need a rule that triggers when the times of two events are closer than the "week" (or whatever) and their temperature difference is less than -7.

Comment: Writing a rule that triggers when the times of two events are closer than the week (or other time block) is really what I'm trying to figure out, here. I should point out that events are never removed from working memory. They will be present a year later, for example. So the logic needs to express that they are within a week... and that they are within the *most recent* week. Thus, your suggestion of adding a now fact which is updated fairly frequently seemed to me a good suggestion, though it seems very strange to me drools doesn't have a native option for handling this.

Comment: Even so... To guarantee that the lower end of the temperature drop has been reached by the last event, you just need to add another pattern that guarantees that there is no later event, i.e., `not Event( this after $second)` and you have tied the interval to "now".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99992/discussion-between-melchoir55-and-laune).

Comment: I missed your invitation but I'll hang around today.

Comment: You can click that link to view the chat. I'd also welcome you contacting me via the email on my profile.